# Not able to set values on Material UI TextField Select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

I am new to React.

I want to build a Form that has a Text field and a dropdown with 2 selections.
The form renders but I am unable to select any values from the dropdown. The `handleChange` function doesnt run.

```
const Category = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

    const [formValues, setformValues] = useState({
        categoryName: "Test",
        categoryType: "Expense",
    })

    const categories = [
        {
            value: 'Income',
            label: 'Income',
        },
        {
            value: 'Expense',
            label: 'Expense',
        },
    ];
    const handleFormSubmit = (values) => {
        console.log(`Submitting : ${JSON.stringify(values)}`);
    };
    const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");
    const handleCategoryTextChange = (event) => {
        console.log(`Category Text Change ${event}`);
        setformValues({
            ...formValues,
            categoryName: event.target.value,
        })
    }
    const handleCategoryChange = (event) => {
        console.log(`Category Change Event ${event.target.value}`);
        setformValues({
            ...formValues,
            categoryType: event.target.value
        })
    };

    return (
        <Box>
            <Box m="20px">
                <Header title="CREATE CATEGORY" subtitle="Create a New Category" />

                <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                    <Box
                        display="grid"
                        gap="30px"
                        gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                        sx={{
                            "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
                        }}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            variant="filled"
                            type="text"
                            label="Category Name"
                            onChange={handleCategoryTextChange}
                            value={formValues.categoryName}
                            name="categoryName"
                            sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            variant="filled"
                            label="Category Type"
                            onChange={handleCategoryChange}
                            value={formValues.categoryType}
                            name="categoryType"
                            sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                            select
                            >
                            {categories.map((option) => (
                                <MenuItem key = {option.value} value={option.value}>
                                    {option.label}
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </TextField>
                    </Box>
                </form>

               </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

I am expecting the dropdown to be selectable and the handleChange events to be triggered.

Once this is working, I would submit the form values to an API endpoint

Comment: there is no state set for ``category`` but you have used ``setCategory``..  your IDE should have pointed that out

Comment: Thanks for replying. I took it out but still doesnt work. I have edited the code

Comment: ok.. will check on this